# Can you force movement without using a power?

Tags: dnd-4e, forced-movement

Are there ways for a character to employ forced movement without using any powers, feats or items of the sort? By that I mean using exclusively skill and ability checks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **Bull Rush** is the first thing that comes to mind when you ask this question.  (I think Brian Ballsun-Stanton's comment is foreshadowing this), which requires a charge attack.

> **BULL RUSH: STANDARD ACTION** *(PHB1, p287)*
>
> - Target: You can bull rush a target adjacent to you that is smaller than you, the same size category as you, or one category larger than
>     you.
> - Strength Attack: Make a Strength attack vs. Fortitude defense. Do not add any modifiers for the weapon you use. Hit: Push the target 1
>     square, and shift into the vacated space.
> - Impossible Push: If there’s no square you can push the target into, your bull rush has no effect.
>
>   ---
>
> **MOVE A GRABBED TARGET: STANDARD ACTION** *(PHB1, p290)*
>
> - Strength Attack: Make a Strength attack vs. Fortitude. Do not add any weapon modifiers. Hit: Move up to half your speed and pull the grabbed target with you.

Beyond those, I can't find any *untrained* ways to move someone (IE powers, feats, etc.) short of Bankuei's reference to DMG1, p42 for improvised actions, the example of which includes a push type action.

Comment: +1 _Bull Rush_ and _Move a Grabbed Target_ are the only untrained ways I'm aware of too!

Comment: Bull Rush doesn't _require_ a charge attack as far as I'm aware (although that's the most common use of it that I've seen). DDI's glossary entry for Bull Rush mentions no such requirement, either.

Answer (score 4):

**"Page 42"**

D&D4E's pg. 42 of the DMG has guidelines for stunts.  The general gist is that as players come up with random stunts, the GM can assign a stat to attack with, a defense stat for it to go against, an amount of damage, and conditions.

"I roll a barrel down the stairs at the goblins" - could/should easily result in forced movement (down the stairs).

Of course, this depends on what objects/terrain is available, the monster(s) you're fighting, and the GM's ruling about each particular stunt you're doing.